# How to get customer in error with Recurring billing using NetBanx (OptimalPayments) API

Tags: c#, api, netbanx-api

I'm using the OptimalPayments API for Recurring Billing.  I would like to create a C# application that use an API who can fetch all the Customer who have a Failed Transaction (ex:  customer with expired credit card).

But I don't know which API URL and Call I should do.  I Looked through the CreditCardWS and ilsLookup API but they doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is late but I want to make sure that this is answered. The API that you are using is not able to get that information. You would need to setup an automated report from our system and then you will be able to obtain that information. Netbanx can provide it in HTML, CSV or Excel.

You can send an email to technical support (technicalsupport@paysafe.com) and they will be able to help you set that up for you.

Hope that this helps!